# UWP app, how change login screen image?

Tags: c#, windows-10

The Windows10 UWP APIs let you change the desktop background image and lockscreen image like so:

```
// set wallpaper
UserProfilePersonalizationSettings profileSettings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;
    if (wallpaper)
    {
        success = await profileSettings.TrySetWallpaperImageAsync(storageFile);
    } // or lockscreen
    else
    {
        success = await profileSettings.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(storageFile);
    }
```

But how would one change the login screen image?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for changing the Login Screen background image.

The image itself exists as an embedded PRI resource that cannot easily be changed (you'll need to hack the PRI file to change the image).

There is a Group Policy setting to hide the image and use a solid colour instead, however there is no Windows Runtime API for modifying Group Policy directly, you must change the registry settings yourself:

1. Locate the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System`
2. Create or set a DWORD value `DisableLogonBackgroundImage` to `1`.